# SQL count там где пусто/null

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

Есть SQL запрос который выводит названия групп в которых содержится меньше 10-ти участников
Но он не выводит те группы в которых нету ни одного участника , как сделать так чтобы выводило так же и пустые группы в которых нету участников ?

```
SELECT GROUPNAME
    FROM STUDENTS s JOIN GROUPS g ON (s.GROUP_ID = g.GROUP_ID)
GROUP BY GROUPNAME
  HAVING COUNT (*) < 10;
```

Comment: Right join.....

Comment: если группы выводить надо, то и выборку делайте из групп, а не из студентов. либо правый джойн

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
GroupName as 'Group Name' 
    FROM STUDENTS s RIGHT JOIN GROUPS g ON (g.GROUP_ID = s.GROUP_ID)
GROUP BY GROUPNAME
  HAVING COUNT (*) < 10;
```